# Creating proxy with bypass list fails if it contains "*"

Tags: powershell, proxy

The code:

```
 New-Object System.Net.WebProxy($Env:http_proxy, $true, @('localhost', '*.domain.com')
```

fails with the error:

```
 New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "3" argument(s): "parsing "*.domain.com" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing."
 At line:1 char:6
 + $p = New-Object System.Net.WebProxy($Env:http_proxy, $true, @('*.domain.com', 'l ...
```

The `Quantifier {x,y} following nothing` is regex error which is strange. I tried to use regex escape chars but nothing.

Any solutions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I messed that up at least twice - the following however seems to add it correctly though one at a time:

```
$wp = New-Object System.Net.WebProxy($Env:http_proxy, $true)
$wp.BypassArrayList.Add('localhost')
$wp.BypassArrayList.Add('*.domain.com')
```

Output

```
Address               :
BypassProxyOnLocal    : True
BypassList            : {localhost, *.domain.com}
Credentials           : 
UseDefaultCredentials : False
BypassArrayList       : {localhost, *.domain.com}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking [at this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144293%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it's stated the third parameter is an array of regex strings - `*.domain.com` isn't a valid regex as a character class must precede the `*`.

It works if you change it to `.*.domain.com` however:

```
[PS] > New-Object System.Net.WebProxy($Env:http_proxy, $true, @("localhost.domain.com",".*.domain.com"))


Address               :
BypassProxyOnLocal    : True
BypassList            : {localhost.domain.com, .*.domain.com}
Credentials           :
UseDefaultCredentials : False
BypassArrayList       : {localhost.domain.com, .*.domain.com}
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't notice that regex info.